# Accepted-Language Preference Order: What if the Wildcard Comes First?

Tags: http, http-accept-language

Let's say I am writing a server which can handle a language set [`en-US`, `en-GB`]. Now, there is a request whose `Accept-Language` is `en, en-US`.

Does it mean the user prefer `en-GB` rather than `en-US`? Or is this a valid case to send to the server?

The only related RFC I found is [RFC 4647](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4647.html#section-3.3.2), but it doesn't directly explain this situation.